# Adding a matrix to a plot?

Tags: r, plot

Is there anyway to add a table to a plot. Suppose that I have the plot below:

```
curve(dnorm, -3, +4)
```

Now I like to add a matrix beneath the plot:

```
testMat <- matrix(1:20, ncol = 5)
```

My goal? I'm writing a plot function that not only does create a plot, but it also shows a matrix including the information I'm interested in underneath the plot.

Please see the attached picture to see what I mean.
I really appreciate your help.

[image]

Comment: If I may put on my Ed Tufte costume for a moment: A graph should stand on its own as a purveyor of information.  I would recommend keeping the table of data values separate (e.g. an Appendix).  If nothing else, this makes it far easier for other people to extract the numbers ("copy and paste") for subsequent use.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are probably better ways to do this, but one option might be to use one of the packages that "plots" matrices and data frames, like the ["gplots" package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gplots/index.html).

Here is a very bare example (you can probably customize this for much finer control over the final layout).

```
# Some sample data
testMat <- matrix(1:20, ncol = 5)
testMatDF <- as.data.frame(testMat)
names(testMatDF) <- c("Hey there", "Column 2", 
                      "Some * Symbols", "And ^ More", 
                      "Final Column")
rownames(testMatDF) <- paste("Group", 1:4)

# Load the package
library(gplots)
# Set par for plotting a three-row plot
par(mfrow = c(3, 1))
curve(dnorm, -3, +4)
textplot(testMat)
textplot(testMatDF)
```

The result:

[image]

You can also use `layout()` instead of `par(mfrow...)` if you want to get a little bit more creative with the placement of your plots. For example:

```
layout(matrix(c(1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3), 
              2, 3, byrow = TRUE))
curve(dnorm, -3, +4)
textplot(testMat)
textplot(testMatDF)
```

[image]

Comment: hi @mrdwab, Tahnks for your answer. I have a little bit of problem with textplot(). My matrix has 5 columns and it only shows the first two columns. Is there anyway that I can reduce the space between columns?

Comment: @Sepehr, see `?textplot` and look for the `cmar` and `rmar` for adjusting the column and row spacing. I'm not sure why you would have the problem you've described without seeing a sample of your data. Other than column spacing, another reason could be the size of your initial plot area; if the plot window is too small, some of the data might be cut off. Hope that helps!

Comment: I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 7):

Package `plotrix` provides function `addtable2plot`.

Example from the help file:

```
library(plotrix)
testdf<-data.frame(Before=c(10,7,5),During=c(8,6,2),After=c(5,3,4))
rownames(testdf)<-c("Red","Green","Blue")
barp(testdf,main="Test addtable2plot",ylab="Value",
     names.arg=colnames(testdf),col=2:4)
# show most of the options
addtable2plot(2,8,testdf,bty="o",display.rownames=TRUE,hlines=TRUE,
              title="The table")
```

**Edit:**
Put the table in a new plot to place it underneath your plot.

```
library(plotrix)

layout(matrix(c(1,2), 2, 1, byrow = TRUE),
       widths=c(1,1), heights=c(2,1))


testdf<-data.frame(Before=c(10,7,5),During=c(8,6,2),After=c(5,3,4))
rownames(testdf)<-c("Red","Green","Blue")
barp(testdf,main="Test addtable2plot",ylab="Value",
     names.arg=colnames(testdf),col=2:4)

plot.new()
addtable2plot(0,0,testdf,bty="o",display.rownames=TRUE,hlines=TRUE,
              title="The table")
```

Comment: I looked at `addtable2plot()` too, but it seemed cumbersome to position the table where I wanted. It seems dependent on the plot window size. Can you update your answer with an example similar to what the OP was looking for (in other words, where the table is below the plot instead of within the plot)?

Comment: awesome. Much better answer now. +1

Comment: Hi Roland, thank you for your answer. For some reasons, I was unable to  run your code. However, I got a very good idea on how to use the function addtable2plot(). Thanks.